# Doctrine Join with composite keys

Tags: postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm

**Main entity Conferimenti.php**

```
/**
 * Conferimenti
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="conferimenti")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ConferimentiRepository")
 */
class Conferimenti
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="bigint", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")
     * @ORM\SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="conferimenti_id_seq", allocationSize=1, initialValue=1)
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Infocomune")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="idcomune", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $idcomune;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Inforifiuti")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="tiporifiuto", referencedColumnName="codicerifiuto"),
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="idcomune", referencedColumnName="idcomune")
     * })
     */

    private $tiporifiuto;
```

**Inforifiuti.php**

```
/**
 * Inforifiuti
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="inforifiuti")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Inforifiuti
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="codicerifiuto", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     */
    private $codicerifiuto;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="idcomune", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     */
    private $idcomune;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="descrizione", type="string", length=80, nullable=false)
     */
    private $descrizione;
```

**Infocomune.php**

```
/**
 * Infocomune
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="infocomune")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Infocomune
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")
     * @ORM\SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="infocomune_id_seq", allocationSize=1, initialValue=1)
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nome", type="string", length=80, nullable=false)
     */
    private $nome;
```

***I am tryng to execute this query (working on Postgres) but can't get it working with doctrine ORM :(***

```
SELECT r.descrizione, SUM(c.peso) as totale
INNER JOIN inforifiuti AS r ON r.codicerifiuto = c.tiporifiuto AND r.idcomune = c.idcomune
WHERE c.idcomune = :id_comune AND c.dataora >= '2019-01-01' AND c.dataora <= '2019-10-30'
GROUP BY c.tiporifiuto, r.descrizione
```

Querybuilder

```
$query = $qb
    ->select(array('r.descrizione','SUM(c.peso) as totale'))
    ->innerJoin('c.tiporifiuto','r', Expr\Join::WITH, $qb->expr()->andX(
        $qb->expr()->eq('c.tiporifiuto', 'r.codicerifiuto'),
        $qb->expr()->eq('c.idcomune', 'r.idcomune')
    ))
    ->where('c.idcomune = :id_comune')
    ->andWhere($qb->expr()->between('c.dataora', ':date_from', ':date_to'))
    ->setParameter('id_comune', $id_comune)
    ->setParameter('date_from', $date_from, \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::DATETIME)
    ->setParameter('date_to', $date_to, \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::DATETIME)
    ->groupBy('c.tiporifiuto')
    ->addGroupBy('r.descrizione')
    ->getQuery();
```

I get this error

**A single-valued association path expression to an entity with a composite primary key is not supported. Explicitly name the components of the composite primary key in the query.**

tryed to replace ->GroupBy with but same error

```
->add('groupBy', new Expr\GroupBy(['c.tiporifiuto', 'r.descrizione']))
```

**UPDATE**
Tryed using direct DQL but same identical error

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery(
    'SELECT r.descrizione, SUM(c.peso) as totale
     FROM App\Entity\conferimenti AS c
     INNER JOIN App\Entity\inforifiuti AS r
     WHERE c.idcomune = :id_comune AND c.dataora >= :date_from AND c.dataora <= :date_to
     GROUP BY c.tiporifiuto, r.descrizione')
    ->setParameter('id_comune', $id_comune)
    ->setParameter('date_from', $date_from, \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::DATETIME)
    ->setParameter('date_to', $date_to, \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::DATETIME);
```

**A single-valued association path expression to an entity with a composite primary key is not supported. Explicitly name the components of the composite primary key in the query.**

Answer (score 0):

try this:
  $this->manager->createQuery('SELECT .........');

like this example :

```
$query = $entityManager->createQuery(
    'SELECT p
    FROM AppBundle:Product p
    WHERE p.price > :price
    ORDER BY p.price ASC'
)->setParameter('price', 19.99);
```

the official documentation: https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/doctrine.html